# Python2 grep command with pipes

Tags: python, variables, grep, environment

I need to identify an environment variable in my following script.

`env | grep -i TIMEZONE | cut -c14-18`

What am I doing wrong? I tried:

```
command = ['env']
command2 = ['grep']
command2.append('-i')
command2.append('TIMEZONE')
command3 = ['cut']
command3.append('-c14-18')

process=subprocess.Popen(command,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,shell=True)

process2=subprocess.Popen(command2,stdin=process.stdout,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
process3=subprocess.Popen(command3,stdin=process2.stdout,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
(out,err) = process3.communicate()
print 'output is :', out
```

Comment: Why are you doing this with external programs instead of using Python built-in functions? `os.environ['TIMEZONE'][14:18]`

Comment: Although high level English is not a requirement here, your questions would be probably better accepted if you would follow at least [these](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291362/advice-for-non-native-english-speakers/291370#291370) simple spelling rules.

Comment: What is the output of your original script `env | grep -i TIMEZONE | cut -c14-18`? I've got an empty output.